# Remove duplicates from array based on values in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array as follows:

```
const array = [
{id: 3, amount: 100, productId: 10, title: "Color/Red", variantChildren: Array(0)},
{id: 4, amount: 5, productId: 10, title: "Color/Green", variantChildren: Array(2)},
{amount: 0, variantChildren: {…}, title: "Color/Red"},
{amount: 0, variantChildren: {…}, title: "Color/Green"},
{amount: 0, variantChildren: {…}, title: "Color/Purple"}
]
```

I need to remove the duplicates that have the amount of 0. I'm trying to figure out how to do this with `.filter()` or `.forEach()`

So items `[2]` & `[3]` would get removed, and returned with a new array:

```
const newArray = [
{id: 3, amount: 100, productId: 10, title: "Color/Red", variantChildren: Array(0)},
{id: 4, amount: 5, productId: 10, title: "Color/Green", variantChildren: Array(2)},
{amount: 0, variantChildren: {…}, title: "Color/Purple"}
]
```

Comment: why not item at index 4?

Comment: Please use standard syntax when displaying data. The easiest way of getting that is to use `console.log(JSON.stringify(objToLog, null, 2))`. Otherwise, we have to wade through comments complaining about syntax where we just don't need to.

Comment: @vr12 because the title is unique, ie: 'Color/Purple'. 2 & 3 should get removed because there are duplicates of 'color/red' and 'color/green', but their amount is 0.

Comment: So, group on `title`, remove the ones that have amount 0?

Comment: how do you choose the one selected in duplicates? It's the last one?

Comment: @HereticMonkey good call. updated the syntax display.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [
  {id: 3, amount: 100, productId: 10, title: "Color/Red", variantChildren: Array(0)},
  {id: 4, amount: 5, productId: 10, title: "Color/Green", variantChildren: Array(2)},
  {amount: 0, variantChildren:{}, title: "Color/Red"},
  {amount: 0, variantChildren: {}, title: "Color/Green"},
  {amount: 0, variantChildren: {}, title: "Color/Purple"},
  {id: 5, amount: 3, productId: 11, title: "Color/Green", variantChildren: Array(2)},
  {id: 6, amount: 10, productId: 12, title: "Color/Red", variantChildren: Array(0)},
  {amount: 2, variantChildren: {}, title: "Color/Purple"},
  {amount: 0, variantChildren: {}, title: "Color/Purple"},
];

const removeZeroAmountDuplicates = arr => {
  // group items by title
  const titleItemsMap = arr.reduce((acc,item) => {
    const { title, amount } = item;
    if(acc[title]) acc[title].push(item);
    else acc[title] = [item];
    return acc;
  }, {});
  // iterate over each title's items
  const res = Object.values(titleItemsMap).reduce((acc, titleItems) => {
    // if list has more than one elements remove zero-amount items, otherwise keep the only element
    const items = titleItems.length > 1
      ? titleItems.filter(item => item.amount !== 0)
      : titleItems;
    // merge items with acc
    return [...acc, ...items]
  }, []);
  return res;
}

console.log( removeZeroAmountDuplicates(data) );
```

Comment: Running your snippet still removed the 'Color/Purple'

Comment: Should be `return !acc`

Comment: @Dileet I updated the answer to cover your conditions

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the array to a Map, only add items that don't exist, or those that exist, and those that exist, but have a total greater than 0.

Convert the Map's `.values()` iterator to an array with `Array.from()`.

```js
const data = [{"id":3,"amount":100,"productId":10,"title":"Color/Red","variantChildren":[]},{"id":4,"amount":5,"productId":10,"title":"Color/Green","variantChildren":[null,null]},{"amount":0,"variantChildren":{},"title":"Color/Red"},{"amount":0,"variantChildren":{},"title":"Color/Green"},{"amount":0,"variantChildren":{},"title":"Color/Purple"}];

const result = Array.from(
  data.reduce((acc, o) =>
    !acc.has(o.title) || o.amount > 0 ? acc.set(o.title, o) : acc, new Map())
  .values()
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var unfiltered = [{amount: 0}, {amount: 0}, {amount: 1}, {amount: 2}]
var tmpArray = [];
var filtered = unfiltered.filter((val, index, arr) => {
  var tmpTrue = !(tmpArray.map(v => v.amount).includes(val.amount))
  tmpArray.push(val)
  return tmpTrue;
});
console.log(filtered);
```

[Filter MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

That code is kind of unreadable. Basically, `filter` maps through the array. The function provided should return true or false. If true, return the current value to the new array, otherwise, skip it. The function I provided maps through the temporary array, which gets updated every value, since we need to check the `amount` for each element. So the mapped array return `amount` for every element. With the new array, we check if `amount` already exists, true or false.

Comment: Hmm I'm getting an empty array from this

Comment: @Dileet I updated it, I had the wrong idea for `filter`

Answer (score 0):

for using `.filter` or `.forEach` you have to check each elements and if this element can find in lower index, remove it.

```js
const array = [
    {id: 3, amount: 100, productId: 10, title: "Color/Red"},
    {id: 4, amount: 5, productId: 10, title: "Color/Green"},
    {amount: 0, title: "Color/Red"},
    {amount: 0, title: "Color/Green"},
    {amount: 0, title: "Color/Purple"}
]

const result = array.filter((el, i) => {
    const dupIndex = array.findIndex(e => e.amount === el.amount)
    return i <= dupIndex
})

console.log(result)
```